# Modernizr Touch Detection Broken

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I'm using a default [Modernizr (2.6.2)](http://modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-mq-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load) build (included in the `head`). I'm on a retina MBPro laptop using Google Chrome (Version 33.0.1750.152) and when I use the following, it alerts `Touch Screen`, thinking I'm on a touch device.

```
if ( Modernizr.touch ) {   
    alert('Touch Screen');  
} else {   
    alert('No Touch Screen');  
}
```

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This doesn't have a problem on the current version of Modernizr, so I'd suggest updating/trying out the newest version first. An easy way to check is to go the Modernizr web page, then to run `Modernizr.touch` in the console to see that it returns `false`.

Comment: It's an old post, but here's the current solution : if (Modernizr.touchevents) {}

Answer (score 2):

`Modernizr.touch` tests for touch *events*, not touch *screens*. More than likely you have the touch sensor emulation checked off in your dev tools

[image]